# Get Database server name of SQL Server without logging in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm connecting my SQL Server 2012. But I get below error message, connection failed.
I'm not sure about my server name (I forgot).

Is there anyway to get the database server name, Windows authentication username and password without logging to SQL Server?

> Cannot connect to MY-SERVER.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name  is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Is SQL server installed on same or different machine? In both cases, server name is going to be computer name, but you may also have to know the instance name if it's different from default.

Comment: In same machine. I gave Default instance when I installed

Comment: If it is local you can use .\ as server name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.`, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for local server with default instance.